# How to introduce custom classloader into Spring Boot Jersey application?

Tags: spring, web, classloader

I have a Spring Boot Jersey Application. I want to use a custom class loader with it to allow loading classes and resources from outside of standard web application classpath. (I need it to allow customers to add "plugins" to the application without disturbing original application file structure). Any suggestions how can I do that?